# Which discard pile for instant items played on another player's lane?

Tags: xenoshyft-onslaught

In XenoShyft Onslaught, in which discard pile goes an Instant Card when played in another player's lane? For example, if I use a "Hi-Ex Grenade" in the reaction phase of another player, do I discard that grenade in my or his/her discard pile?

For references, the rulebook only mentions what happens for troops and equipment played in another player's lane. Nothing about Instant Items:

> - Note that you can deploy a Troop in a lane that is not your own. If you do so, the owner of that lane becomes the owner of that Troop (it goes to their discard pile if killed).
> - A player may also at this time equip Troops with the various Equipment Cards they has purchased. To do so simply place the Equipment Card under the Troop you wish to equip it to. It is now equipped to that Troop. A Troop can only have one Weapon Card and one Armor Card equipped at any time. Just like with deploying Troops, you may also Equip Troops that you do not own. If you do so, the owner of that lane becomes the owner of that Equipment card (it goes to their discard pile if the equipped Troop is killed).

The "Hi-Ex Grenade" has the "Instant Keyword":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the official FAQ (not included in the box published by EDGE) published on CMON website (game creator) : https://cmon.com/product/xenoshyft/xenoshyft-onslaught

> Q: If I play an Instant on another player’s lane (such as a Med
>   Pack or Hi-Ex Grenade), does that card go to their discard
>   pile?
>   A: No, it goes to its owner’s discard pile. The only time a card
>   goes to another player is if it is deployed into their lane.

Keeping Instant Cards played on someone else's lane in one's own discard pile allows us to better "build" around Division Cards abilities (such as "Whenever you play a [Symbol] card, heal 1 troop up to 2").